# Add type for onClick property which is in ...props in React TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a button component in which I'm trying to write the prop types using `type` and I see this error in the console. Could anyone please help?

```
Type '{ children: string; label: string; onClick: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'.
  Property 'onClick' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'.  TS2322
```

Excerpt from my code

```
type Props = {
  label: string;
  children: ReactNode;
};

const Button = ({ label, children, ...props }: Props) => (
  <button label={label} {...props}>
    {children}
  </button>
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `onClick` into `Props` like:

```
type Props = {
  label: string;
  children: ReactNode;
  onClick: () => void;
};
```

Comment: Looks like the error is no more. But, if I don't pass label for `Button` component, It says `label` is missing in type. Is there a way can I make it optional?

Comment: `label?: string`